# Proposals being considered for dealing with deceased future colonists on Mars or Elsewhere in the Cosmos

Tags: mars, death

This question assumes that in the future a sizeable colony of humans might be established on Mars, or elsewhere.

On Earth, one common way to deal with the dead is burial. This system relies on microbes consuming the soft tissues and thereby transferring nutrients back to Earth.

Life on Mars has not been discovered. So for now, it can be assumed there would be no natural way to decompose the bodies of deceased colonists. Sending the bodies to Earth would be expensive and would require procedures to ensure unpleasant conditions did not eventuate aboard the vessel taking the bodies to Earth. Cremation would use vital oxygen supplies. Burial would most likely result in corpses remaining as they are, either frozen or desiccated, similar to the [Inca mummies](https://www.thevintagenews.com/2017/11/26/inca-mummies/) found in Argentina in 1999. One idea I came across was to have the bodies [composted](https://futurism.com/the-byte/mars-colonists-compost-dead-human-bodies) and the nutrients used a fertilizer for plants.

Have any protocols been developed by anyone that addresses what would be done with deceased colonists?

Comment: resomation, or rendering

Comment: I assume "compositing" was a typo, as the linked article talks about composting. In general composting relies on microbes. <BR>Sending the bodies to earth isn't likely to be that expensive, as the craft would be flying anyway (cost per Kg *doesn't* work that way)

Comment: These are not necessarily duplicates but they are somewhat related: [What are the sanctions to prevent Mars being polluted with human corpses?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26825/12102) and also [What happens if we bury a human on other planets or moons](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/5666/12102) (closed for "needs more focus" because each planet is different) and only slightly related [What happens to a body, that has been exposed to vacuum, once brought back onboard?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17623/12102)

Comment: and related in SciFi: [1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/123321/51174), [2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/104020/51174)

Comment: @JCRM: Thank you for the correction.

Comment: I can personally vouch for the fact that a number of influential brothers and sisters of our Islamic communities have considered this question from a cultural/theistic perspective...fascinating!

Comment: One influencing factor is what the colonists/astronauts want. Do they want to come home, or be left on Mars? Do they care?

Comment: @GdD: An interesting idea, but there is also the precedent of expeditionary military forces creating war graves in countries where military personnel have died in battle: ie [The Somme](https://www.visit-somme.com/great-war/military-cemeteries) & [Normandy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_cemeteries_in_Normandy). Military personnel usually don't have an option about how their bodies are dealt following death in battle. Maybe the same would have to apply to future cosmic colonists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think we have a good general idea of properly dispose or treat garbage anywhere above LEO. Or further, we are not good at dealing with garbage in general, on or above earth, or we won't have a world wide garbage problem now.

That said, human body is a very challenging biohazardous waste so special care must be taken compared with other waste.

Burial isn't a terrible option IMO. The nuclear waste we bury on earth, toxic mining byproducts piled into mountains, dead satellites in GSO, aren't going anywhere in a thousand years either but somehow we've been OK with that. It does takes space but not an unacceptable amount. It's relatively safe and cheap as well.

More modern option would be [alkaline hydrolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaline_hydrolysis_(body_disposal)) which is much cheaper and energy efficient.

When human civilization evolves to that level I hope it will be social custom that remains of the deceased are recycled/salvaged and/or properly disposed of responsibly.

Comment: I've up voted because I think the answer is instructive about how disposal *should be* considered in the future in spaceflight contexts, and for the mention of alkaline hydrolysis (and It makes me want to ask if it was ever used on the Sopranos in Movies SE) but the question asks for *Proposals being considered* so answers should try to address that directly. Is it possible to add a link showing that besides you, just now, that demonstrate that alkaline hydrolysis or other processes *are being considered?* Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh I'm not aware any of such proposals. But eventually there will be I believe.